# Accessing Docker running on Host machine from VMWare Workstation VM

Tags: docker, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have the following setup:

- Windows 10 Host (Hyper-V enabled)
- Docker Desktop installed on host
- VMWare Workstation Pro (16)
- Windows 10 VM - Docker CLI installed on vm

The Windows 10 VM is used as a dev environment, with project-specific stuff on there.

I also use the host as a development machine for other projects - so want to be able to use docker on both.

What I'd like to do is access the docker engine running on the host, from my VM
By access docker, I mean use the docker cli to run containers, build images etc... setting `DOCKER_HOST` or something like that?

Is this possible? Or any other way?

So far, I've set my VM to use NAT networking and tried:

`docker -H tcp://192.168.126.2:2375 images`

Which returns

> error during connect: Get http://192.168.126.2:2375/v1.40/images/json: dial tcp 192.168.126.2:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

`192.168.126.2` is the ip of the default gateway, from within the VM (so - my host?)

On the host machine, if I do  `docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 images` I get the expected result.

On the host machine, I've also set:

`"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"],`

within the docker engine config:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

so what i would do and usually am doing is in VMware Workstation in Network editor I connect VMs to a bridge and select my main line that provides connectivity whether it is an Ethernet port or Wifi and associate it to lets say VMnet0. Then in VM settings I assign that VM's NIC to VMnet0 and that is how my VM and my host are on same LAN.
I would not use NAT.